# Libreoffice menu text not displaying correctly

Tags: 17.10, 17.04, libreoffice, fonts, menu

This question has a similar problem but no solution and mine differs from it slightly: [Libreoffice text not displaying properly on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/904926/libreoffice-text-not-displaying-properly-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Installed the IBM Plex font a while back and use it on my Ubuntu machine. Updated my Ubuntu yesterday from 17.04 to 17.10 and then updated all the packages including LibreOffice and now LibreOffice doesn't display menu text correctly (picture below). It worked before I updated to 17.10.

According to the above question, the font needs to be installed for it to work however my font is already installed but I am getting the same problem. I have gone through and checked that all the fonts are installed correctly and this didn't fix the problem.

This is what LibreOffice Writer looks like when I start it up:
[image: This is what Libreoffice Writer looks like when I start it up]

This is what is output when I start LibreOffice from console:

```
(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'IBM Plex Sans 11'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'IBM Plex Sans 11'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: shaping failure, expect ugly output. shape-engine='PangoFcShapeEngine', font='IBM Plex Sans 11', text='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'IBM Plex Sans Medium 11'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'IBM Plex Sans Medium 11'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: shaping failure, expect ugly output. shape-engine='PangoFcShapeEngine', font='IBM Plex Sans Medium 11', text='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'IBM Plex Sans Bold 11'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'IBM Plex Sans Bold 11'

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: font_face status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: scaled_font status is: out of memory

(soffice:10778): Pango-WARNING **: shaping failure, expect ugly output. shape-engine='PangoFcShapeEngine', font='IBM Plex Sans Bold 11', text='The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.'
```

I have tried moving the `.ttf` files to `/usr/share/fonts/` in a new folder but that didn't work either. I have tried reinstalling LibreOffice but that also didn't work.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest LibreOffice update fixed this issue.

If you're having this issue, check if there are any outstanding updates to install.